# Can Lupa be used to run untrusted lua code in python?

Tags: python, lua, lupa

Let's say I create `LuaRuntime` with `register_eval=False` and an `attribute_filter` that prevents access to anything except a few python functions. Is it safe to assume that lua code won't be able to do `os.system("rm -rf *")` or something like that?

Comment: It's probably safer to compile a custom Lua with all I/O libraries and other stuff you'd want to prohibit ripped out. Even then, a DOS attack is easy (just write an infinite loop).

Comment: @delnan Good point, my current plan is to spawn a separate process and use the `resource` module to limit CPU and RAM usage

Comment: In general, only ever execute untrusted code if you life absolutely, positively depended on it.  Like, some holds a gun to year head and/or to the heads of your loved ones threatening to shoot if you don't.  Just assume that *any* sandbox can be broken out of (and yes, a DoS is even easier).  Google Chrome had breakouts.  Any VM had breakouts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From looking at the [Lupa doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa/#restricting-lua-access-to-python-objects):

> **Restricting Lua access to Python objects**
>
> Lupa provides a simple mechanism to control access to Python objects. Each attribute access can be passed through a filter function as follows...

It doesn't say anything about preventing or limiting access to facilities provided by Lua itself. If no other modifications are done to the `LuaRuntime` environment then a lua script can indeed do something like `os.execute("rm -rf *")`.

To control what kind of environment the lua script works in you can use the `setfenv` and `getfenv` to sandbox the script before running it. For example:

```
import lupa
L = lupa.LuaRuntime()
sandbox = L.eval("{}")
setfenv = L.eval("setfenv")

sandbox.print   = L.globals().print
sandbox.math    = L.globals().math
sandbox.string  = L.globals().string
sandbox.foobar  = foobar
# etc...

setfenv(0, sandbox)
```

Now doing something like `L.execute("os.execute('rm -rf *')")` will result in a script error.